# Clang Error in Google Analytics in Xcode 7.2 and Mac osx 10.11.2

Tags: xcode7.2

Google Analytics was working fine in below version of Xcode 7 but after updating to Xcode 7 getting clang error.

I did these steps to add GA library :

1.

Added Google Analytics in the Xcode folder having name **Google Analytics**  [image]

2. Added libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a into this folder as well as added in Build phase in Link Library by referencing  libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a from the xcode folder (inside the Google Analytics .a file is added by selecting add other )

**Works Fine .**

But the strange thing happening , 
***whenever i quit Xcode and again open libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a is  showing in this build phase link library*** .
But now there is Clang Error :

[image]

**Note - Bitcode setting to No (Since current library doesn't support bitcode so Bitcode setting to No in Xcode setting )

Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , after so much RND issue Solved.

Target & Project setting Header Search Path added these entries .
Here is Snapshot :

[image]